# Running a single test in WebStorm using Jest

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jestjs, configuration, webstorm

I'm trying to run single test in my project. However every time I use triangle run icon WebStorm creates new configuration for me.

I'm adding screenshots to clarify what is happening exactly now when I run a single test.

[image: Tests]

[image: Configuration]

Is there a way to provide one predefined config instead of this?

Comment: a separate configuration is required for each test, as configuration parameters are different, so it works as expected

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **Edit configuration templates...** button on the bottom left corner of the Run/Debug Configurations menu. This way every time WebStorm creates a new configuration it will use the preset one you have specified
[here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOd6p.png).
You can save those as project files, meaning it will be automatically read by WebStorm for you and others